# Columns Into Rows Using Oracle10g

Tags: sql, oracle10g, unpivot

I'm using Oracle 10g and I want to convert a row into a column.

I have a data like this:

```
ID | HOMEADD | HOMETEL | WORKADD | WORKTEL
------------------------------------------
1  | HOME1    | 1234   | WORK1   | 4321
```

How can I make a result like this:

```
ID | TYPE | ADDRESS | TEL
---------------------------
1  | HOME | HOME1   | 1234
1  | WORK | WORK1   | 4321
```

Is there a way to UNPIVOT this using 10g?

Answer (score 1):

This you can easily achieve by using "UNION".

```
select  id, 'home' as type, homeadd as address, hometel as tel from table1
Union all
select id, 'work' , workadd, worktel from table1
```

Full script:

```
create table table1 (id number, homeadd varchar2(500), hometel varchar2(50), workadd varchar2(500), worktel varchar2(50));
insert into table1 values (1,'HOME1',1234,'WORK1',4321);
select  id, 'home' as type, homeadd as address, hometel as tel from table1
union all
select id, 'work' , workadd, worktel from table1;
```